# How would you use "beside" as an adverb?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs

So in my Collins grammar book, it says that *beside* is a preposition that can **also be used as an adverb**, but I can't find any examples of it being used as an adverb.

Was it perhaps a typo? Was it meant to be *besides* not *beside*?

Comment: Answers so far ignore parallels in the arguably adverbial usage of various other prepositions, as in *those who have gone before* or *a dragon lurks within.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not a typo. Some dictionaries describe the use of *beside* as an adverb [archaic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/beside).

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/beside) defines it as:

> ***adverb***
> along the side of something:
>
> - The family rode in the carriage, and the dog ran along ***beside***.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beside) records two archaic uses of besides:

> ***beside** adverb*
>
> 1. archaic : NEARBY
> 2. archaic : BESIDES

In fact ***besides*** comes from ***beside***:

> Old English had the phrase ***be sidan***, “*by the side of*.” OE side meant the flanks of a person, or the long part of anything. By 1200 the phrase was written as one word and used as ***both adverb and preposition***. ([dailywritingtips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/beside-and-besides/))

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/beside) notes that

> The alternative Middle English meaning "outside" is preserved in ***beside oneself*** - "out of one's wits" (late 15c.).

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my first post and you have made it a great experience.

Answer (score 1):

In present-day speech, the only adverbial use of *beside* is as a synonym of *besides* with an *s*.

But archaically, it could also mean various things, including as a synonym for *alongside*, so to the side of something or nearby. The OED provides this citation (amongst others):

- 1798   S.T. Coleridge *Anc. Marinere* ɪᴠ, in W. Wordsworth & S.T. Coleridge *Lyrical Ballads* 23
     The moving Moon went up the sky..And a star or two beside.

That means that the moon had a star or two nearby or beside it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my first post and you have made it a great experience.